# Read a file in a Java EE Web Project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

I am using Intelli-J Idea IDE and working on a Java EE Web project. I am trying to read `words.txt` file. The code is working fine in command line, but when I deploy the code into glassfish server it gives me "FileNotFoundException".

File is located in "src/Analyser/pWords.txt"

Code to read the file content:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("src/Analyser/pWords.txt"));
```

After searching StackOverflow, I found out that I need to add this file to resources directory. Unfortunately, I am unable to create resources. When I create the package `main` and the resources in the `src` folder, the package becomes `main.resources`, I tried another way such as:

```
InputStream inputStream  = new FileInputStream("src/Analyser/pWords.txt");
```

AND

```
InputStream inputStream  = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("src/Analyser/pWords.txt");
InputStream inputStream  = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("pWords.txt");
```

But the result is `null` or `error`.

So is there any way I can read the file from `src/Analyser/` directory in my project? It's a Java EE Web project.

**UPDATE:**

From the Project Structure > Artifacts > `WEB-INF` folder, I uploaded the `pWords.txt` file. and Now finally, BufferedReader is not empty, while debugging I can see that `bufferedReader` contains data. But when I copy the data to a string variable, the variable remains null. I am quite confused about it.

Code:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream stream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("pWords.txt");
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    String t = "";
    try {
        while((t = bf.readLine()) != null) { // in debugging, (cb) contains the char data as char elements.
            t += bf.readLine();  // but t = null
        }
    } catch(IOException x) {

    }
```

Comment: You cannot use a file system in Java EE.  You should be opening an input stream for a classpath resource.  Should not be source.  /resources should be in classpath.  Read relative to the root of your package.

Comment: @duffymo how can I add resources to the classpath? secondly, I am unable to create resources dir either.

Comment: Unable to create?  Of course you can.  I would recommend using the standard Maven directory structure and building your Java EE package using IntelliJ artifact.  The src/main/resources contents go into CLASSPATH automatically.

Comment: @duffymo please check the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have two problems/erros within your code!

1.) You are using the variable t in two ways. On the one hand you are combining the results by `t += bf.readLine();` and on the other hand you are overwriting t with further input from the stream by `(t = bf.readLine()) != null`. Since this is the abort condition of the while loop, t has ALWAYS to be null in the end!

2.) You are calling `bf.readLine()` two times - in the while condition and again within the loop. If you read the API/javadoc of `readLine()` then you'll get to know that this two calls will return 2 different(!) results. This way, if the stream (`bf`) only contains one line of text, then in your condition the call of `bf.readLine()` will return your line of text and when you try to add it to the variable `t` then your (second) call of `bf.readLine()` will return null, since the end of the stream has been reached.

Possible solution:

```
String singleLine;
String wholeText = "";
try {
    while((singleLine = bf.readLine()) != null) {
        wholeText += singleLine;
    }
} catch(IOException x) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nix try this

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                                .getResourceAsStream("Analyser/pWords.txt”);
```

Comment: `this` cannot be referenced from a static context. I get this error.

Comment: Can you post your entire class?

Comment: It's a static class, so I am unable to use `this` because it's non-static. I am just having an issue with the method, I updated the question please check.